# How could I create 2 same XML-Tags by using SimpleXML in PHP?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have wrote this PHP code to create a XML data:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Products></Products>");
$xml->addChild("Product");
$xml->Product->addChild("Name", "P1");
$xml->Product->addChild("Price", "10");
$xml->addChild("Product");
$xml->Product->addChild("Name", "P2");
$xml->Product->addChild("Price", "20");
```

The XML what I got is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>P1</Name>
    <Price>10</Price>
    <Name>P2</Name>
    <Price>20</Price>
  </Product>
  <Product/>
</Products>
```

But what I want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>P1</Name>
    <Price>10</Price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Name>P2</Name>
    <Price>20</Price>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

How could I get the right XML? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple change to this should do it...

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Products></Products>");
$product = $xml->addChild("Product");
$product->addChild("Name", "P1");
$product->addChild("Price", "10");
$product = $xml->addChild("Product");
$product->addChild("Name", "P2");
$product->addChild("Price", "20");
```

The problem is you were re-selecting the first element from the XML root when adding your sub elements.

Comment: Too easy, please accept my answer if you found it helpful.